# Wilcard binding in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7, bindings

**Scenario**
Domain is *mydomain.com*
Website host IP is *1.2.3.4*

I have setup the DNS for *.mydomain.com to point to 1.2.3.4

**Requirement**
I need to route incoming requests for *.mydomain.com to a single site in IIS 7.5

e.g. site1.mydomain.com, site2.mydomain.com must all be directed (bound) to the same site in IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're using Microsoft DNS:

Create an A-record in the zone mydomain.com with the value "mydomain.com" and the IP 1.2.3.4. Will show up in the MMC as (same as parent folder).

This will redirect any undefined subdomains to the default web site running on the IIS.

Comment: This is what I have done so far, now my problem is routing those requests that arrive at IIS running on 1.2.3.4 to the same site i.e. subdomain.mydomain.com AND subdomain2.mydomain.com AND subdomain3.mydomain.com